# Django send_mail error using smtp.domain.com (smtplib.SMTPHeloError: (501, b'Syntactically invalid HELO argument(s)'))

Tags: django, email

I have a problem when sending an email using Django as the email I'm trying to send from is hosted on domain.com, I've tried to send from Gmail and it worked fine but when I use the configuration of domain.com it gives me this error: smtplib.SMTPHeloError: (501, b'Syntactically invalid HELO argument(s)')
what I understand is that it is related to the host name, but I don't know what to do to fix that error and can I use a different hostname for domain.com that works. below is the configuration in setting.py and send_mail function:

setting.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.domain.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'Name@emailFrom.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "********"
```

send_mail function:

```
send_mail(
        'HR Request',
        'your request is being processed',
        'Name@emailFrom.com',
        ['Name@emailTo.com'],
        fail_silently=False,
    )
    return HttpResponse('Mail sent')
```